# Style - background-image not showing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Can someone please tell me why my background-image isn't showing up? This is my style.css layout? I've tried numerous codes but for some reason the image just won't show up. Please help me, it's for a project.

```
<style>

.body {
  background-image: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2ngegih.png'); 
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: left top;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}


#heading {
  text-align: center;

}

#left {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 200px;
}

#middle {
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 700px;
  width: 810px;



}

#right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 90px;
}
 <style>
```

This is my header page:

```
<div id="heading">
<div class="heading">

<title>MediaBuzz</title>
<center><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/vdjsqx.jpg">
</center>
</div></div>
```

This is the index page. All these pages are all I've got since I just started.

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<div id="left">
<div class="left">
this is the left column
</div></div>


<div id="middle">
<div class="middle">

this is the middle column 
</div></div>

</style>
</div>
```

Comment: Give .body a height.

Comment: may be `body` instead of `.body`?

Comment: I tried both and none worked. :(

Comment: Can you post a complete code example in your question then? Include your HTML.

Comment: Side note, the `<center>` element doesn't exist any longer. Use CSS to center content. Also, none of the elements in your HTML example have a body class.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need a period for selecting the `body` element. Not sure if you're using `body` as a class name. Please post the rest of the HTML page.
- That url points to an HTML page but not the raw image itself. Try using `http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ngegih.jpg`

Edit:

That is invalid HTML.

The body element or class does not exist, and so your CSS declaration will not be applied. You need to learn the basic structure of an HTML page. Make use of the W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/

You also need a PHP server running to interpret the PHP code in there.

The following code should answer your question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MediaBuzz</title>
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
body  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ngegih.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- the rest of the HTML goes in here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a comment, not answer.

Comment: I got rid of the period and used the jpg image instead and still nothing. I posted the header page if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I added all that I've got.